# linux ssh key copy from already created by a server Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/loadbalancer' are too open

Tags: linux, ssh

I have to copy the whole ssh folder from one server to another to avoid to  copy the ssh keys to other server but I'm getting this error.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/loadbalancer' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /root/.ssh/loadbalancer
```

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556119/ssh-private-key-permissions-using-git-gui-or-ssh-keygen-are-too-open

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's your error…

> Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/loadbalancer' are too open.

To fix it:

> It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.

The [file permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) are `0644`. That means, the owner has read and write permissions, and group and others have read permissions. Of course, this is not what you want.  A private key should only be readable by your user.

Fix it by changing permissions:

```
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/loadbalancer
```

Comment: good job.
working great :)

Comment: @HassanSohail Of course, you should “protect” all files in this folder with appropriate permissions. Just use `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*` to protect everything in the folder.